# Can you estimate an application's performance before testing?

Tags: performance, load-testing, benchmarking, performance-estimation

It's a tricky question I was asked the other day... We're working on a pretty complex telephony (SIP) application with mixed C++ and PHP code with MySQL databases and several open source components.

A telecom engineer asked us to estimate the performance of the application (which is not ready yet). He went like 'well, you know how many packets can pass through the Linux kernel per second, plus you might know how quick your app is, so tell me how many calls will pass through your stuff per second'.

Seems nonsense to me, as there are a million scenarios that might happen (well, literally...)

However... is there a way to estimate application performance (knowing the hardware it will run on, being able to run standard benchmarks on it, etc) before actual testing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You certainly can bound the problem with upper (max throughput) limits.  There is nothing nonsense about that.  In fact, not knowing that stuff indicates a pretty haphazard approach to a problem - especially in the telephony world.

You can work through the problem yourself - what is the minimum "work" you have to accomplish for a transaction or whatever unit of task you have in your app?

Some messages to and from, some processing and a database hit for example? Getting information on the individual pieces will give you an idea of the fastest possible throughput. If you load up the system and see significantly lower performance then you can take time to figure out where you are possibly losing throughput with inefficient algorithms, etc.

**EDIT**

To do this exercise you need to know all the steps your app does for each use case. Then you can identify the max throughput for each use case. You should definitely know this stuff prior to release and going live.

I'm ignoring the worst case analysis as that - as you point out - is quite a bit harder.

Answer (score 3):

See [Capacity Planning for Web Performance: Metrics, Models, and Methods](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136938221). There are also some tools that can do this sort of discrete event simulation:

- [Hyperformix](http://www.hyperformix.com/products/performance-optimizer)
- [SimPy](http://simpy.sourceforge.net/)
- [WikiPedia list of simulation tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_simulation_software)

This stuff ain't easy, and the commercial tools will cost ya. The Capacity Planning book comes with a CD with lots of Excel workbook templates and examples of models that can jump start you.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

If you really have to answer this you could say something like this:

"I don't know off the top of my head. I am will to estimate this for you but it will take time. Obviously the accuracy of my answer depends upon how much effort (I.E. time) I put into calculating my estimate. How much time should I put into calculating my estimate?"

Put the burden back on them. If they really want an accurate answer, they're going to have to let you build at least some test applications that can simulate the actual environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can spike to measure performance. Your whole system may not be working yet, but you know how the parts are intended to fit together. You can whip something up in a few hours that does the same kind of work as the final app will, across all the layers, and use it to measure performance of your design.

**Remember:** prototypes are broad, spikes are deep.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do capacity planning in advance, but the quality of the estimate will depend on the quality of the data available.

The best estimate is to build the system in test, run simulated workloads, then predict capacity as a function of performance requirements and workload. These 3 form a prediction space - given 2 of the 3, you can predict the third:

1. Given performance requirements and capacity (i.e. hardware) you can calculate the workload you can handle.
2. Given performance requirements and workload, you can calculate the capacity (i.e. hardware) that you need.
3. Given Workload and capacity, you can predict your expected performance.

Answer (score 1):

You should do the estimate. An estimate won't give you the right answer. It will however make you to think about the problem. Right now it sounds like your coding and hoping that everything will be OK. Or you are in panic mode and feel you don't have time for estimates.

Spend some time thinking about it. Analyse the important use cases. Think about the memory you may need; think about database access; think about network access (local and remote). These will effect the performance of your system. Get the whole team together to do this.

Regularly measure your system's performance during development for these important  use cases. Mock up components/other systems if you have to. Analyse the results. How do these compare to your estimate. Maybe components are memory/database/network bound. Maybe you need more memory; less database access; simpler queries; caching. You don't have to make these changes straight away. However you do know how your system operates and what you need to do.

**Result:** Fewer nasty surprises at system test. Less panic as the release date looms.

Answer (score 0):

This is true in some domains, but unless you are an expert in that domain then you don't have any idea. For example I write code to controlling industrial robots. The speed is limited by the robot motion, not by the execution speed of the code. Knowing how fast the robot is and how far it has to go, we can make fairly good estimates of "speed". I'd have no idea how to estimate time for your application.